# Magento2 post to products/SKU changes website

Tags: magento2, rest-api, tierprice, tiered-pricing

I am using Magento 2.1.2 and when I update tier price information using the REST api, the product in website value is modified.

For instance, I issue a `POST` request on `/{website}/V1/products/{sku}/group-prices/{customerGroupId}/tiers/{qty}/price/{price}` my Tier prices are OK but the product is being added to other website it was not part of before the tier price update.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the API which website you want to update -  if you say you're adding {website} then it's not going to work.

The way to do this with REST API is to include the store code (child of the website you'd like to update) within the URL.

POST http://www.domain.com/rest/{store_code}/V1/products/{etc}

Give it a try, if it doesn't work then hopefully someone else will be able to assist. The REST API is a bit lacking/buggy when it comes to scope.

Refer to documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/rest_endpoints.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this is already what I am doing.

Comment: Are you having issues creating/updating products also? If not, then perhaps try adding a tier price within the product object to see what happens.  If you're using the correct store code then it should be in that particular scope and not add any more sites - although as mentioned, it seems like the web API was a bit of an afterthought.